# Scraping Tables on a Web page with BeautifulSoap

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, html-table

I need to do a DataFrame in Python with the information of Top 500 Americas Companies:

https://www.americaeconomia.com/negocios-industrias/estas-son-las-500-mayores-empresas-de-america-latina-2021

I tried to do web scraping and when I print(tabla) it said [] or None...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.americaeconomia.com/negocios-industrias/estas-son-las-500-mayores-empresas-de-america-latina-2021'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

tabla = soup.find('table', {"id":"awesomeTable"})
print(tabla)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Always look in your soup first - therein lies the truth. The content can always be slightly to extremely different from the view in the development tools.

You won't find the table in your soup, cause it is in iframe.

#### How to fix?

Use the url of the iframe source to perform your request:

```
https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/500-latam/2021
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://rk.americaeconomia.com/display/embed/500-latam/2021',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
data = []
for row in soup.select('#awesomeTable tbody tr.dataRow'):
    data.append(list(row.stripped_strings))

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list(soup.select_one('#awesomeTable tr').stripped_strings))
```

#### Output

| RK 2021 | EMPRESA | PAÍS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PETROBRAS | BRA |
| 2 | JBS | BRA |
| 3 | AMÉRICA MÓVIL | MX |
| 4 | PEMEX | MX |
| 5 | VALE | BRA |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thank!!!! is possible to extract the data inside each Companie?

Comment: If you click, there is another table with a lot of information.

Comment: Hi HedgeHog! thank you for your help! I cant do any more Q for a day..... but could you please help me with this?